# jquery click event not being triggered in production mode angular5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5

I am using jquery this [plugin](https://github.com/bopoda/ace) in my angular 5 app .
 I have nested accordion menu on left side. When I run app in **development mode** the menu works fine it opens and close as accordion menu as expected , but when I run the app in production mode by running command

`ng build --prod`

then click event triggered only once it opens the menu and then never being triggered (menu remains open ) . I have used angular cli to include menu js script in my angular app. what could be the solution of this problem.
Thanks in advance
here is component ts file

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery'
declare var ace :any;
@Component({
selector: 'app-sidebar',
templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html'
})

export class SidebarComponent {
currentDate:Date;
constructor( @Inject('Window') window: Window) { }
ngOnInit() {
$("#sidebar-collapse").on("click", function () {
  $('body').toggleClass('menumin');
});
this.currentDate=new Date();
 }
 ngAfterViewInit() {

ace.demo.init();

}
}
```

here is html file

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar responsive ace-save-state">

  <ul class="nav nav-list">
    <li class="productname">
      <a  class="mjms_nav">

        <span class="menu-text"> MJMS </span>
        <em>
         {{currentDate | date:'MMM-dd-yyyy'}}</em>
      </a>

      <b class="arrow"></b>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['/home/dashboard']">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-tachometer"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
      </a>

      <b class="arrow"></b>
    </li>

    <li routerLinkActive="open">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
        <span class="menu-text">
          Education Management
        </span>

        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
      </a>

      <b class="arrow"></b>

      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="open">
          <a href="#0" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>

            Admission Information
            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>

          <ul class="submenu">

            <li routerLinkActive="active">
              <a [routerLink]="['/education/admission/applicants/new']">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                New Applications
              </a>

              <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>
            <li routerLinkActive="active">
              <a [routerLink]="['/education/admission/confirmed']">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Confirmed Applicant
              </a>

              <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>
            <!-- <li class="">
              <a href="entry_test_list.html">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Entry Test List
              </a>

              <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>
            <li class="">
              <a href="final_batch.html">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Final Batch
              </a>

              <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li> -->
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Class Activity
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Results
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Co-Curricular activities
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Class Scheduling /Time table
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Course Upload
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Attendance
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Examination and results

          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Hostel management
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  
    <li routerLinkActive="open">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> Financial Management </span>

        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
      </a>

      <b class="arrow"></b>

      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Payroll

          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li routerLinkActive="open">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            <span class="menu-text">
              Manage Fee
            </span>

            <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>

          <ul class="submenu">


            <li routerLinkActive="active">
              <a [routerLink]="['/finance/fee/group']">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Fee Group
              </a>

              <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>

            <li routerLinkActive="active">
              <a [routerLink]="['/finance/fee/category']">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Fee Category
              </a>

              <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>

            <li routerLinkActive="active">
              <a [routerLink]="['/finance/fee/structure']">
                <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                Fee Structure
              </a>
              <b class="arrow"></b>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            General Ledger


          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Balance Sheet
          </a>
          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a >
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Income Statement
          </a>
          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-cube"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> Assets Management </span>

        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
      </a>

      <b class="arrow"></b>

      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Inventory
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Assets Assignment
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Assets Tracking
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Procurement
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>



      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-th"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> HR Management </span>

        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
      </a>

      <b class="arrow"></b>


      <b class="arrow"></b>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="">
          <a href="HR_emp_personalInfo.html">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Employee Profile
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Attendance
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Leaves
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Benefit & incentives
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Promotion Management
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Performance management
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="#">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-envelope"></i>

        <span class="menu-text">
          Communication Management

        </span>
        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
      </a>


      <b class="arrow"></b>

      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Notice Board
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Notification
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>





      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="#">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-th-large"></i>

        <span class="menu-text">
          Administrative Management

        </span>
        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
      </a>


      <b class="arrow"></b>

      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="">
          <a href="Dashboard-Admin.html">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Directors Dashboard
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>
        <li class="">
          <a href="Dashboard-teacher.html">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Teachers Dashboard
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a href="Dashboard-student.html">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Students Dashboard
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>

        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Parents Dashboard
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>





      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="#">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-check"></i>

        <span class="menu-text">
          User Rights Management

        </span>
        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"></b>
      </a>


      <b class="arrow"></b>

      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="">
          <a href="#0">
            <i class="menu-icon fa fa-caret-right"></i>
            Portal Admin
          </a>

          <b class="arrow"></b>
        </li>










      </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon fa fa-power-off"></i>
        <span class="menu-text"> Logout </span>

      </a>

      <b class="arrow"></b>


    </li>


  </ul>
  <!-- /.nav-list -->

  <div class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-collapse" id="sidebar-collapse">
    <i id="sidebar-toggle-icon" class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left ace-save-state" data-icon1="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left"
      data-icon2="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the component code? Important section of html and ts ...

Comment: I added have a look @Sunil

Comment: In "my" point of view, This is not the right way to build an app using angular 5. You are mixing jquery with angular which is a bad way of doing. Like I told you, this is "my" point of view. Thanks.

Comment: Also you have given html file which is having side bar section. You should have given Accordion section. Also update the question with accordion click function in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You should use binding click event in template

in html

```
<div class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-collapse" id="sidebar-collapse" (click)="collapseSideBar()">
```

and in component

```
collapseSideBar() {
  $('body').toggleClass('menumin');
}
```

Comment: Im not talking about this . this working fine. I have accordion men on left which is not opening up

Comment: accordian menu can be opened and closed based on the toggle class of body element.

Comment: accordion menu opening function is written in script file which i include through angular cli file . it works for first time only

Comment: Recommended way of binding click event should be by angular way from template